# How can I configure Magento Salable Quantity

Tags: out-of-stock

When I add a new product in Magento 2, The Salable Quantity is 0, and there the product shows out of stock on the end user.

Comment: Which version are you using of magento2 ?

Answer (score 0):

By default magento takes a while to update the quantities depending on how cron is set up.

Do this x3 times
php bin/magento cron:run
and after php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

if you have solved it depends only on the slowness with which it does this operation otherwise you have either set something or installed a module
Do you have a version lower than 2.4 ? or have you set up flat tables ?

Answer (score 0):

****You need to add the quantity of a particular Product and as well as check the Stock Status of in-stock/Out of Stock for Particular product****